# I try to make it blink, but it won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create notifications system in my company's ERP, similar to Facebook one. For now, after few hours of work, it looks like this:

[image: example]

Each menu item is a `li`element. Each element can have one of classes that will modify it's background color:

- `selected` is blue, shown on a picture
- `restricted` is red

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to make `li` background blink on some events (when new message comes in and list is not opened (and also `selected`class is not present)).

**The problem is: it won't blink. :(**

here's snap of my html (excluding messagebox)

```
<li class="notifications-topmenu-button selected">
  <a href="#">
    <div class="notifications-topmenu-button-wrapper">
      <div class="notifications-topmenu-button-icon">
        <img class="transparent" width="13" height="13" align="absmiddle" src="/images/icons/notifications.png" title="Powiadomienia" alt="Powiadomienia">
      </div>
      <div class="notifications-topmenu-button-counter" style="display: block;">3</div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <span class="divider"> : </span>
</li>
<li class="selected">
  <a href="/system_dev.php/users/profile">Strona główna</a>
  <span class="divider"> : </span>
</li>
```

Also, there's some JavaScript initiating object (don't mind comments):

```
function notificationsObject(){
  var nl = new Object();

  //atrybuty klasy
  nl.liElement = $('.notifications-topmenu-button');
  nl.menuButton = $('.notifications-topmenu-button-wrapper');
  nl.menuButtonCounter = nl.menuButton.find('.notifications-topmenu-button-counter');
  nl.notificationsCount = jQuery.trim(nl.menuButtonCounter.text());
  nl.notificationsList = $('.notifications-list-wrapper');
  nl.blinkingInterval = null;

  nl.startBlinking = function(){
    nl.blinkingInterval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(nl.liElement.hasClass('restricted') == false){
                                          console.debug(nl.liElement.addClass('restricted'));
                                        } 
                                          else {
                                            nl.liElement.removeClass('restricted');
                                          }
                                      }, 1000);
  }

  nl.stopBlinking = function(){
    if(nl.blinkingInterval != null) nl.blinkingInterval = null;
  }

  (more 'class' functions)

  return nl;
}
```

Now to test it, I simply call

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var notifications = notificationsObject();
  notifications.startBlinking();

});
```

Of course I call it after function declaration.

funny fact is that when I change `nl.startBlinking` function `setInterval` internals to only add `restricted`class, it works. I'm pretty sure it must be some typo or stupid error, but I can't find it.

Please, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved.

the thing was that this function

```
nl.startBlinking = function(){
    nl.blinkingInterval = setInterval(function(){
                                        if(nl.liElement.hasClass('restricted') == false){
                                          console.debug(nl.liElement.addClass('restricted'));
                                        } 
                                          else {
                                            nl.liElement.removeClass('restricted');
                                          }
                                      }, 1000);
  }
```

started executing on declaration.

so when I called

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var notifications = notificationsObject();
  notifications.startBlinking();

});
```

I had not one, but two intervals working at the same time.

Comment: Don't think that was it, it's not an "immediate function" and you only call it once. Here is another Fiddle with a console.log('started'), to show it is only called once http://jsfiddle.net/w9SDH/. Glad you got it sorted though.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer (when you can) for future reference for others.

Comment: Ben - that's true. In fact, the problem lied somewhere else. Further in my `notificationObject()` function I made something similar to `construct` - just a set of functions to execute at startup. One of them was to check if notifications count is greater at 0, and then change page title and... execute blinking. It's my stupid mistake, but, to be honest, you guys helped me find it anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the toggleClass function instead of checking classes yourself like:

```
setInterval(function(){
    nl.liElement.toggleClass('restricted');                                       
}, 1000);
```

jQuery reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Hi! I've tried that before I ran into `if`-`else`. Unfortunately, it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I put all your code into a Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5LXFp/) and it worked. Not sure what the problem is.

added css

```
.restricted{
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Also removed `(more 'class' functions)` line. But I assume you just added that to the post and it's not part of your code.

Comment: The problem is that `restricted` is `background-color: red`, but, of course, it doesn't matter. I just starred on firebug's html output for a while and I saw that, in my case, `restricted` class is never added by JavaScript to the code.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, have you fixed it? I have changed css to background-color and it still seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/aXS2Z/

Comment: Ben, I added new answer and solution below. Thanks for your help anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add and remove the 2 classes in stead of only restricted

```
if(nl.liElement.hasClass('restricted') == false){
                                           nl.liElement.addClass('restricted');
                                           nl.liElement.removeClass('selected');
                                        }
                                          else {
                                           nl.liElement.removeClass('restricted');
                                           nl.liElement.addClass('selected');
                                          }
```